# Odoo-8 -- How can I add a button next to the "Create" button in the "Human Resources" -> "Employees" Kanban view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Unfortunately I can't post pictures with a reputation lower than 10. 8-/

In a inherited view I want to add a button beside the red "Create" Button in the employees Kanban view. You can reach it over the menus "Human Resources"->"Employees".

I've searched for that button in the "hr_view.xml" file but couldn't find it so I assume that it isn't part of the view but it reacts on switching through the views (kanban to list to form view) so there must be a relation anywhere!? 
But where is this relation defined?

Now I tried the following code out to add a simple action button which I wanted to place in the (new) "header" of the view:

```xml
<?xml   version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="view_kanban_hr_employees_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field  name="name">HR - Employees Kanban extension</field>
            <field  name="model">hr.employee</field>
            <field  name="inherit_id" ref="hr.hr_kanban_view_employees" />

            <field  name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="name" position="before">
                    <header>
                        <button string="Calculate Employee Timeaccounts" name="button_calc_employee_timeaccounts" type="object"/>
                    </header>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

The result is that every kanban vignette now has that (small) button with no text in it. 
What I wanted to achieve was to only add one button at th top of the page and didn't want to add a button to every single kanban vignette.

Does anyone have suggestions for me? Where should I insert the button?? 
The nicest solution would be right beside the red "Create" button on top. But like I mentioned before I think this isn't part of the inheritable view.

Seeing forward for great solutions and thank you for reading!

Comment: I didn't try it but maybe: `<header position="inside"> ... </header>`

Comment: Doesn't the header-tag already has to be in the parent view so that I can access the header area with this technique? But there isn't a header-tag in the hr_view.xml. I'm wondering if a header-tag is designated to be in a kanban view? Or can I only add a header-tag to the form view?

Comment: Hello , See I think the thing is where you wanted to add button are in a generic class it will be view on every model, so its not a good idea. So here I suggest you two option 1. Add your button under More menu which is beside cancel button 2. or else you can add to top-bar which same as Create Opportunity Button in Leads. Tell me If you want anything more.

Comment: Hi, I can't see a "More" menu. Which cancel button do you mean? 
I don't exactly understand your second option.

Comment: okay sorry, see here 1. http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/620374/7c6badd897bb9874c9ad81e3e65002a3 2. http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/620377/569683d73965aea4d9363ca5ffd3a6d1

Comment: Thank you very much for the screenshots! Now it's clear to me. So you mean that it is impossible to add such a button to the kanban view.
I think the more menu would be good option. How can i add an entry to that drop-down list and execute a python method within my model?

Comment: There is lots of example already in other modules you can have look. Please dont thank me on stackoverflow, You can upvote my any answer ;) hahaha

Comment: I can not vote for comments. Which module do you suggest me to look in for a example?

Comment: You can have a look on CRM and HR